# What if date on recommendation letter is wrong?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I received a letter of recommendation from my internship coordinator and the year  the letter is dated to says 2021 instead of 2022. It clearly seems like a mistake but I’m worried that it will render the letter invalid since it looks like it was from over a year ago when it was written a just a few days ago.

Since my internship coordinator was the one who submitted it, does it really matter if the date is wrong?

Comment: I would always keep some kind of written evidence (Emails, texts), for anything, even though it may not matter. It doesn't hurt to clarify about the mistake to your coordinator.

Comment: Who is the target audience of the letter?

Answer (score 17):

Nobody is going to notice, and whoever does will not care. It's not a question for you to spend emotional energy on: mistakes happen, move on.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I'm under the impression that the older a recommendation letter is, the less weight it carries. By implication, the date on the recommendation letter matters.

Comment: @Allure my assumptions is, OP received email with the letter attached from the coordinator, to notify OP that the coordinator already submitted his recommendation to whoever needed it. As the coordinator themselves submitted the letter, I doubt that it matters that much, but if it were up to me, I would ask for clarification.

Comment: @Allure I am certain that 80% of readers will not notice the mistake. And the other 20% will realize that the letter was uploaded to the portal two weeks ago by the letter writer and that the year-old date is therefore, in all likelihood, a mistake,

Answer (score 9):

Just send them an e-mail back letting them know about the issue. Probably they have sent out multiple letters whilst forgetting to update the date, so they might be happy to be notified so they can correct it for everyone.